# sticky header on scroll with CSS issues

Tags: javascript, css

I've built a sticky header that appears when you scroll past the navigation area, and everything works great except that when I adjust the window size, the sticky header doesn't adjust automatically until I reload the page, even though width is at 100% and the position is fixed. Every other div adjusts automatically, but not this one (maybe because of the javascript that clones it from the stationary header?). So, the bug I can't figure out how to fix is making .floatingHeader adjust automatically when I change the window size without reloading. Any ideas on how to fix this small aesthetic bug?

My HTML:

```
 <div class="persist-area">
    <div class="top">
    <div class="persist-header">
         <div class="head">
            <div>
                <div class="home active" onClick="location.href='index.html'"></div>
                <a href="#">About</a><a href="#">Contact</a>

                <div class="home right"></div><a href="#" id="right">News</a>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
```

The CSS:

```
.floatingHeader {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 99999;
}
```

And the Javascript:

```
function UpdateTableHeaders() {
   $(".persist-area").each(function() {

       var el             = $(this),
           offset         = el.offset(),
           scrollTop      = $(window).scrollTop(),
           floatingHeader = $(".floatingHeader", this)

       if ((scrollTop > offset.top) && (scrollTop < offset.top + el.height())) {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "display": "block"
           });
       } else {
           floatingHeader.css({
            "display": "none"
           });      
       };
   });
}

// DOM Ready      
$(function() {

   var clonedHeaderRow;

   $(".persist-area").each(function() {
       clonedHeaderRow = $(".persist-header", this);
       clonedHeaderRow
         .before(clonedHeaderRow.clone())
         .css("width", clonedHeaderRow.width())
         .addClass("floatingHeader");

   });

   $(window)
    .scroll(UpdateTableHeaders)
    .trigger("scroll");

});
```

Answer (score 0):

The DOM ready event fires when the browser has constructed the DOM tree (so all the elements have be parsed and placed in the correct spot in the tree). But at this time the CSS has not been parsed and applied to the DOM. So when your JavaScript executes, the browser has not yet applied the `width: 100%` to the `.persist-header`. Thus jQuery is just returning the actual width (in pixels) of the element as a default. And that value is what is applied to the cloned element.

If you wait for `window.load` instead, your code will work as intended. (Well, the clone part with; I can't say about the rest ;^)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had the exact same issue. I found that I needed to "resize" the  JavaScript event. I added this function and it worked for me. I hope this helps.

```
     $(document).ready(function () {        
      $(window).resize(function() {
      $(".floatingHeader").css("width",$(".persist-header").width());
    });
 });
```